# using pandas to replace header of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have an XYZ file in the following format

```
X[m] Y[m]  DensD_1200c[m] 
   625268.27    234978.67    7.24   
   625268.34    234978.52    7.24   
   625268.38    234978.45    7.24   
   625268.43    234978.37    7.24   
   625268.47    234978.30    7.24
```

I'm using this code to read it into python via `pandas` and turning it into a shapefile.

```
input_file = "C:/input_file.xyz" # hard-coded for the minute - to be changed
file_extension = os.path.splitext(input_file)[-1].lower()
output_file = input_file[:-4]


if file_extension == ".xyz" or ".asc":
    df  = pd.read_table(input_file, skiprows=2, sep=r'\,|\t', engine='python', names=['x', 'y', 'z'])
    df.columns = ["x", "y", "z"]

elif file_extension == ".txt" or ".csv":
    df = pd.read_csv(input_file, sep='\,|\t')
    df.columns = ["x", "y", "z"]
        

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=df.apply(lambda row: Point(row.x,row.y,row.z), axis=1))

gdf.to_file(f"{output_file}.shp") # hard-coded for the minute - to be changed
shapefile = f"{output_file}.shp"

print("Shapefile Created!")
```

However, I'm wondering is there a way to remove the header column containing text and replace it with X, Y ,Z?

Note: not all files will have headers so I need a way of recognising if theres a header, and replace such with XYZ

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the column names in [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) using `names=[...]`. You then need to explicitly mention that the first line is a header:

```
pd.read_csv(..., header=0, names=['X', 'Y', 'Z'])
```

or with skiprows:

```
pd.read_csv(..., skiprows=1, names=['X', 'Y', 'Z'])
```

output:

```
           X          Y     Z
0  625268.27  234978.67  7.24
1  625268.34  234978.52  7.24
2  625268.38  234978.45  7.24
3  625268.43  234978.37  7.24
4  625268.47  234978.30  7.24
```

Comment: if there is no header in a file, will this replace the first line of data?

Comment: if there is no header, then don't use the `header` parameter

Comment: This needs to be a generic script, so I need it to recognise if there is or isn't a header

Comment: @hello_12039 I see, can you then provide some more examples? You won't be able to recognize the header automatically with `read_csv`, you'll need to preprocess the file. Also give the constraints (if header, it is always only 1 line? more? max?)

Comment: Yes the header is always on 1 line. The files are either as above (with a header) or no header and the first line ```625268.27  234978.67  7.24```

Comment: how can one identify a header? Is it always starting by a non-digit character? Can the data have non numerical characters? etc. Hard to generalize without more examples ;)